# Matlab - set plot Xaxis range according to the right argument

Tags: matlab

Having `n` vectors with same size (also`n`) held in `v_1  , v_2 ..., v_n` . I want to `plot` all of them together such that the Xaxis range will be `1..n` and Yaxis value of each vector would be as its element according to X value  .

Something like  - 
`plot(1:n,v_1,v_2,...,v_n)`

**Edit:**

Fixed as @Phonon suggested .

How could I obtain the above ?

Comment: This makes no sense. Do you mean that want your x-axis to go from 1 to *m* rather than *n*?

Answer (score 1):

You're pretty much on the right track already.

Assuming all your `v_1, ... v_n` are the same length and are each row vectors:

```
plot(1:m, [v_1; v_2; ... v_n]);
```

You could also plot them one at a time via:

```
figure;
plot(1:m, v_1);
hold on;
plot(1:m, v_2);
plot(1:m, v_3);
...
plot(1:m, v_n);
```

This second approach will ultimately give you more control over the attributes of each line in your plot.

If you need to change the limits of your x axis later, you can do this through the `xlim([])` function or the `set(axHandle,'XLim',[lowerLim, upperLim])` command.

Comment: For your second approach I recommend `hold all` instead of `hold on` as this way the graphs will automatically all be different colours